# Bizarre issue with chain rule seems to prove $f(2x)=f(x)$ without defining $f$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

Let us say we have a function $f(2x)$, and let us say $u = 2x$.

It should be clear by the chain rule that
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(2x) = 2f'(2x) = 2f'(u) = 2\frac{df}{du}$$
Now
$$\frac{df}{du} = \frac{df}{dx}\frac{dx}{du} = \frac12\,\frac{df}{dx}$$ So the expression above simply becomes
$$\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}f(x)$$ Thus we have seemingly proven that $f(2x) = f(x)$ without defining $f$?

I do not understand what is going on here but I am clearly confusing something about derivative rules.

Comment: You’re confusing your $f’$s.

Comment: Your $\frac{df}{du}$ is a very ambiguous notation.

Comment: How do you get $f(x)=f(2x)$?

Comment: I think I’ve already told you in your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4736225/568204) how to properly make sense of the situation, and that indeed the two $f$’s on the two sides of the equation mean completely different things. But here are some more answers where I elaborate on notational issues [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3797758/568204), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3270436/568204) and the various related links.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with writing f'(u) as df/du

Comment: When you write "we have a function $f(2x)$", are you aware that that it's actually a composition of two functions? And that you haven't **named** that function (which is a bad idea since you will want to refer to that function later)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $u = 2x$, then by the chain rule,
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(2x) = f'(2x) \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(2x)
 = 2f'(2x) = 2f'(u) = 2 \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm du}f(u).\tag1
$$

Another way to write the same application of the chain rule, but substituting $u = 2x$ earlier, is
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(2x) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(u)
 = \left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm du}f(u)\right) \frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx}
 = 2f'(u) = 2 \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm du}f(u).
$$

Now you can also apply the chain rule like this:

$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm du}f(u)
 = \left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(u)\right) \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm du}
 = \frac12 \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(2x). \tag2
$$

If you use Equation $(2)$ to substitute for $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm du}f(u)$
on the far right-hand side of Equation $(1)$, you will find that
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(2x)
 = 2 \left(\frac12 \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(2x)\right)
 = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(2x),
$$
as you might expect.

What you **cannot** legitimately do is to write
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm du}f(u)
 \stackrel?= \left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(\color{red}{x})\right)
 \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm du}.
$$

In general,
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm du}f(u)
 = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(x)
 \neq \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(u), \text{ where $u = 2x$}.
$$

---

As mentioned already by others, the fatal flaw in your argument has to do with the Leibniz notation $\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dx}$.
You can get away with this notation when $f$ is actually a variable whose value is determined by $x$. But if $f$ is literally the name of a function, you need to provide a value of that function in the Leibniz notation, for example,
$\frac{\mathrm df(x)}{\mathrm dx}$ or $\frac{\mathrm df(u)}{\mathrm dx}$.

What you did in the question was to write $\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dx}$ in a place where only $\frac{\mathrm df(u)}{\mathrm dx}$ makes sense,
but later you reinterpreted the same value of $\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dx}$
as $\frac{\mathrm df(x)}{\mathrm dx}$.
In other words, you misused the notation $\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dx}$
to silently replace $f(u)$ with $f(x)$. No wonder you derived the incorrect conclusion then that $f(u) = f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks, David! Makes sense.

Comment: The last paragraph should perhaps get more focus; that's where the error is really pinpointed.

Answer (score 0):

I will write out a way to think of this situation with clear notation.

Take a function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and denote the doubling function $u:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ given by $u(x)=2x$, whose derivative is $u'=2$. With this information define a new function $F:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ by $F=f\circ u$. Then
$$F'=(f\circ u)'=(f'\circ u)\cdot u'= 2(f'\circ u).$$
Evaluating at $x$, you get
$$F'(x)=2f'(u(x))=2f'(2x).$$
Now with the $d/d$ notation, probably the best way to write this is
$$\frac{dF}{dx}(x)=2\frac{df}{du}(2x)$$
or something like that. The problem is that everyone has their own rationale for how to use the $d/d$ notation.

Edit: I want to clarify something about the use of language. A function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a function of one variable and hence it can only be differentiated with respect to one thing: its argument. The result of differentiating $f$ is another function $f':\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ defined by
$$f'(a)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}.$$

Now, the phrase "the derivative of $f$ with respect to $u$" refers to this function $f'$ evaluated at $u$. But it is still the same function $f'$, just evaluated at another point $u$. That is
$$f'(u)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(u+h)-f(u)}{h}.$$

Comment: In the way I wrote it, what is the proper way to express f'(u) in d/d notation?

Comment: Simply $f'(u) = \dfrac{\mathrm d f(u)}{\mathrm d u}$ .  So if you wish to substitute $u=2x$:  $$f'(2x) = \left.\dfrac{\mathrm d f(u)}{\mathrm d u}\right\lvert_{u=2x}$$

Comment: Your $f'$ is $f$ differentiated with respect to $u$, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Ahdhehshdjdj I edited my post to address your last comment. Please see if that makes sense to you.